# Is it possible to programmatically read terminal contents from OSX terminal without tmux?

Tags: macos, shell, tty, pty

If a shell is running inside `tmux`, I can run `tmux capture-pane` to capture exactly what the user sees as a string.

If a shell is running in the naked OSX terminal, I can run `tty` and get an output of `/dev/ttys000`.
However, if I simply `cat /dev/ttys000` in a different terminal, it does not give me what the user sees.

**Is there some programmatic way (e.g. set of system calls) to access what the user sees in a non-tmux shell?**

Comment: probably not. The tool you would need to capture it is called... tmux. You could also consider taking a screenshot

Comment: If I remember correctly: yes (it depends on terminal capabilities, but most terminals, but the very minimal one) should support it). But my help terminate here. I pretty sure i saw such terminal "commands" ("escape codes"), but I never did it, and so I would have difficulty to find where I got such information. Check terminal capabilities and ESC sequences (and it may be possible that terminal will forbid you to read part of screen that you didn't have control.

Comment: The command is `i`: `CSI .. i`, see https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html How you should figure out hot to capture the output 9or "setup the printer" to a file.

Comment: _in a different terminal_ : I hope you don't want to record in a terminal X what's going in terminal Y, without cooperation of the program running in terminal Y?

Comment: "A different terminal" is a stand-in for "in a background thread" in the same terminal.